Why does the argument for Newton's 3rd law for lift of wings still exist?
I had recently seen a video which explained the various explanations for lift and one of them mentioned about the newtons 3rd law. It stated that the airfoil shape causes the airflow to go down causing the plane to up but that does not work for the planes which have symmetrical airfoils.
This principal was also mentioned by this answer somewhere else.
Then, why isn't this principle ruled out for the possible reason?

You already linked an answer that literally says "Lift can be explained in several, equivalent ways", none of which contradict Newton's third law. So what's your question?

@Bianfable yes they do not contradict the Newton's 3rd law but my question was how would it would it provide lift in the case of symmetrical airfoil.

@Bianfable I do know about the 3rd law. The question is not about its violation of it. When the air passes from the upper side, it gets pushed down by inertia which causes an opposite reaction pushing the plane up. But, the same thing happens from the bottom side of the wing pushing the air upwards. Don't these 2 effect cancel each other in the case of symmetrical airfoil?

@SambhavKhandelwal At zero angle of attack the effects cancel out at there is no lift produced. A non-zero angle of attack breaks the symmetry.

Why shouldn't a symmetrical airfoil produce lift? If it's at an angle in respect to the freestream then it does produce lift pushing air downward. Note that even a not-symmetrical airfoil also has an angle at which it produces 0 lift

Do you have the link to that sh... ehm, video?

It's easier to visualize mentally by thinking about a helicopter rotor. Its blades are just wings going in a circle. The blades are symmetrical on older helicopters, but they still produce substantial lift, in the form of downwash, because although symmetrical they are still moving through the air at an angle and inducing a package of air above and below the blade to accelerate down. Modern helicopters used cambered blade airfoils which are more efficient because composite blades are torsionally stiff enough to absorb the twisting moment from the higher pitching moment of a cambered airfoil.

You seem to be suggesting that some random u-tubers possibly misunderstood interpretation of aerodynamic lift is sufficient to render one of the most fundamental laws of physics to be either useless or irrelevant. The cool thing about physics is you can test ideas yourself.  Next time you are in a car, stick your hand out the window with your fingers pointed into the wind. No lift. Point them a little up and then a little down. Feel the force? Now cup your fingers a little to make your hand shaped like an aerofoil and repeat the exercise. Then you can go back a leave a comment on that video.

Yeah, I have experienced that @PaulSmith. Thanks for helping me find a connection with everyday life

Lift is produced by two effects: Camber and angle of attack.
Symmetrical airfoils do without camber and rely purely on angle of attack.
How this works is explained here.

So symmetrical airfoils can't fly straight and have to be pitched up a little?

@AadirajAnil Yes, If you want to create lift!

"Lift is produced by two effects: Camber and angle of attack" I do not agree: camber only shifts the AoA for 0 lift but it doesn't contribute to lift, only AoA strictly contributes to lift.

@sophit That is a matter of perspective. A cambered airfoil at the same geometric AoA will produce more lift compared to a symmetrical airfoil. Only when you count AoA from the individual zero-lift angle will the lift be about equal. Still, lift distribution over chord and maximum lift will differ.

This answer is correct but not complete. Lift is the vertical component of displaced medium (air) that is greater than gravity. Camber and AoA are important factors in working out the resulting force, but so are density, velocity, viscosity, compressibility and area.

@PaulSmith Thank you for mentioning this. I was until now completely unaware of these important facts.

I would argue that the airfoil meets the relative wind with either a positive or negative angle of attack, causing a pressure (force) differential between its two sides. That pressure differential will result in a third-law force in the opposite direction.

Okay, but then the plane can't maintain a level flight

@SambhavKhandelwal Why? Note that an airplane in general doesn't fly exactly where the nose is pointing. It's perfectly fine to be pitched up somewhat while flying level.

Hmm but that increases the overall front area exposed on the front of the plane which increases drag!

Everybody has own mental model, and we like to simplify things, so sometime it works, sometime not. With your symmetrical air-foil you may notice that some explanation doesn't work well on such case.
The main problem: airplanes are complex, and Newton's motion laws works well with simple bodies, but with more complex cases... you should be careful. Is centre of mass/lift/... moving? What about air? We cannot assume it is homogeneous and without much disturbance (and air has much reaction).
But we cannot do a full FME simulation or Navier-Stock solution. Airbus and Boing will approximate, and with huge computational cost (and still: they will tests to validate models), not something we can do mentally to check how things will change when flying. So we need good but simple mental model (and possibly knowing the limits).
And sometime the problem is about people not strong on physics but with good experience flying (or just confirmation bias): when they want to explain things, they may accept wrong model, if it gives the same results as in real world.
PS: physics has never absolute statements. Underlying physics there are always assumptions and limitation we tend to forget. (Just remember the Gravity laws (of Newton): it was well know the problem of infinity, nobody take the laws as absolute truth), we may tend to forget it.
